# add header to CCheckBoxColumn in TbGridView

Tags: checkbox, yii, header, widget

I add checkboxcolumn in widget TbGridView but I want to add header to CCheckBoxColumn in TbGridView but when I add header I can not see header text why?
I search in internet and  I found if i remove  selectableRows i have header but i can not select all

```
  array( 'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'selectableRows' => 2),
```

Comment: did you add  `'header'=>'Selected',` in above array?

Comment: yes but i have not any result

Comment: did you try Topher solution?

Comment: @kumar_v i did Topher's proffer but when i add 'headerTemplate' i have not celectall option

Comment: do you want to add select all option in header?

Comment: @kumar_v if i donot add header i have selectAll option by default but when i add headerTemplate , i have not selctAll

Comment: you can add either your own text or select all checkbox only.

Comment: @Kumar_v i have 2 checkboxColumn in my table i must to add header :(

Comment: you can add multiple CCheckBoxColumn. one for select all and another for header

Comment: why? what do you want exactly? can add some more code?

Answer (score 3):

For any GridView Column you can add a header using the `header` property. However, for a [`CCheckBoxColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn):

> When in multiple checking mode, the header cell will display an additional checkbox, clicking on which will check or uncheck all of the checkboxes in the data cells. The header cell can be customized by `headerTemplate`.

```
array(
    'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
    'headerTemplate'=>'Column header {item}',
    'selectableRows' => 2,

)
```

Comment: ohhh excuse me topher , when i added headerTemplate , i have not select all why?

Comment: Have you set `selectableRows` to `2` or more?

Comment: I have tested the code above. The 'select all' checkbox works provided you explicitly set `selectableRows` to `2`.

Comment: i have not any solution really?